# Can I use jQuery to detect if any CSS styles exist for an ID?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking for a way to check if any CSS styles are applied to an(y) ID and if not, remove the ID attribute.

Example:

HTML

```
<div id="content-67">
  <h2 id="headline-23" class="page-title">Welcome</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content-67 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The desired outcome would be the removing the ID attribute for H2, because no styles for #headline-23 exist.

```
<div id="content-67">
  <h2 class="page-title">Welcome</h2>
</div>
```

I've been using this rather inefficient solution, which doesn't do the job very well, because it doesn't check the CSS files.

```
jQuery('div,span,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,a,p,img').not('#xyz).removeAttr('id');
```

Could this be done with jQuery or does it need a different solution?

Thanks!

Comment: while your solution is still valid you can do
$("*").not("#xyz').removeAttr('id')
This make the code more clean. It would be easy to answer if you elaborate the use case

Comment: Reading the current computed styles does not give you any indication where they came from. You will not be able to differentiate between styles explicitly set via the site’s own stylesheet(s), and those coming from the User Agent stylesheet. I think if anything, you will have to go through the actual stylesheets and their rules (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet), and check each of them for whether they apply to your current element. Very high effort, probably not going to perform well … likely not worth the struggle to begin with.

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @CBroe thanks, I wasn't sure if there's a simple solution to this, but it sounds like leaving the attributes as they are is less problematic than trying to find a way to remove them.

Comment: @charlietfl I thought of removing attributes that are being added by e.g. plugins / a page builder which clutter the code. Since they're empty, why keep them.